# how to use spyMargin with ng-scrollable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the ng-scrollable directive inside a uib-popover.
I want to use the spyMargin setting to be able to load more items when the scrollbar reaches a certain point just like facebook does with it's notifications.

Here is the how I have used the directive:

```
<div class="scrollable-container" ng-scrollable="{scrollX:'none',scrollY:'right', spyMargin: 0.75}">
```

As far as I can tell, you set the spyMargin to a value between 0 and 1 depending where you want the event to be emitted. In the controller I listen for the scrollable.spybottom event as per described in the documentation, and just print to the console to see if it is working.

```
$scope.$on('scrollable.spybottom', function (e, contentTop, id) {
    console.log("Near the bottom!");
});
```

However, nothing ever gets outputted to the console, so obviously I am doing something wrong. Here is a link to the ng-scrollable homepage: https://github.com/echa/ng-scrollable

I've also created a plnkr to show how this is not working: https://plnkr.co/edit/q6Fdtpjb697SISW8oyHP?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you made all right. The problem is located in [ng-scrollable](https://github.com/echa/ng-scrollable) itself. I checked the source code and found a lot of pattern errors and wrong AngularJS behaviors in that library. The problem is depending on the isolated scope behavior of AngularJS directives. Please take a look at this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Qu7QUExYfDU7GR8IrICr?p=preview) where I fixed the wrong `$broadcasting` handling of `ng-scrollable`. Take a look the file `ng-scrollable.min.js` line `264 to 274`.

This will work for you but it should be better to make a pull request on [GitHub ng-scrollable](https://github.com/echa/ng-scrollable).

```
// fire scrollSpy events only when entering a margin
if (contentTop < containerHeight * config.spyMargin && oldTop >= containerHeight * config.spyMargin) {
  $scope.$emit('scrollable.spytop', contentTop, config.id);
}
if (contentTop > contentHeight - containerHeight * (config.spyMargin + 1) && oldTop <= contentHeight - containerHeight * (config.spyMargin + 1)) {
  $scope.$emit('scrollable.spybottom', contentTop, config.id);
}
if (contentLeft < containerWidth * config.spyMargin && oldLeft >= containerWidth * config.spyMargin) {
  $scope.$emit('scrollable.spyleft', contentLeft, config.id);
}
if (contentLeft > contentWidth - containerWidth * (config.spyMargin + 1) && oldLeft <= contentWidth - containerWidth * (config.spyMargin + 1)) {
  $scope.$emit('scrollable.spyright', contentLeft, config.id);
}
```

After fixing that you finally are able to listen to `$broadcast` events inside your AngularJS controller:

```
// Code goes here
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', ["ui.bootstrap", "ngScrollable"]);

myModule.controller('myController', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {

    //we listen here to see if the scroll-bar spybottom is working
    $scope.$on('scrollable.spybottom', function (e, contentTop, id) {
        console.log("Near the bottom!");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: @TomO'Brien Cheers m8 =)